# google oauth smtp access token for sending only

Tags: oauth, smtp, gmail

i am developing an app for sending emails via gmail smtp. Authentication is done via oauth... is there a way to authorize access to sending email only? and not checking inbox? that way if the access tokens and consumer tokens are somehow compromised, the hacker won't be able to actually read the user's inbox which is more serious issue than sending spams i guess.

Answer (score 2):

No, the scope allows full access to SMTP, IMAP and POP.

Refer **[xoauth2_protocol oauth_20_scopes](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/xoauth2_protocol#oauth_20_scopes)**